# Jquery Listbox Change event does not fire on Keyboard scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've got a simple Listbox on a HTML form and this very basic jQuery code

```
//Toggle visibility of selected item
$("#selCategory").change(function() {
    $(".prashQs").addClass("hide");
    var cat = $("#selCategory :selected").attr("id");
    cat = cat.substr(1);
    $("#d" + cat).removeClass("hide");
});
```

The change event fires fine when the current item is selected using the Mouse, but when I scroll through the items using the keyboard the event is not fired and my code never executes.

Is there a reason for this behavior? And what's the workaround?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `onchange` event isn't generally fired until the element loses focus.  You'll also want to use `onkeypress`.  Maybe something like:

```
var changeHandler = function() {
    $(".prashQs").addClass("hide");
    var cat = $("#selCategory :selected").attr("id");
    cat = cat.substr(1);
    $("#d" + cat).removeClass("hide");
}

$("#selCategory").change(changeHandler).keypress(changeHandler);
```

You'll want both `onchange` and `onkeypress` to account for both mouse and keyboard interaction respectively.

Comment: but i got that keypress in this case is not working in any browser except FireFox, i tested on chrome, safari and IE and didn't work.

Comment: `keypress` event didn't work on chrome but `keyup` worked correctly

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the change behavior can differ per browser, as a workaround you could do something like this:

```
 //Toggle visibility of selected item
    $("#selCategory").change(function() {
        $(".prashQs").addClass("hide");
        var cat = $("#selCategory :selected").attr("id");
        cat = cat.substr(1);
        $("#d" + cat).removeClass("hide");
    }).keypress(function() { $(this).change(); });
```

You can chain whatever events you want and manually fire the change event.

IE:

```
var changeMethod = function() { $(this).change(); };
....keypress(changeMethod).click(changeMethod).xxx(changeMethod);
```

Comment: You're right to say that this is due to cross browser incompatibility.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe, the change event triggering by keyboard scrolling in a select element,  is actually an Internet Explorer bug. The [DOM Level 2 Event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html) specification defines the `change` event as this:

> The change event occurs when a control
>   loses the input focus and its value
>   has been modified since gaining focus.
>   This event is valid for INPUT, SELECT,
>   and TEXTAREA. element.

If you really want this behavior, I think you should look at keyboard events.

```
$("#selCategory").keypress(function (e) { 
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
  if (keyCode == 38 || keyCode == 40) { // if up or down key is pressed
     $(this).change(); // trigger the change event
  } 
});
```

Check a example [here](http://jsbin.com/acila)...

Comment: How can I produce this behavior in Firefox then? I want my content to be updated on listitem changed while the focus is still on the box.

Comment: +1 I found the solution use keyup event in addition to change.

Comment: You should note that keyup will not get called if a keydown is pressed and held until the key is let go, the browser may roll through different items in the list as the key is being pressed.  I would make sure that won't negatively effect any code that relies on active changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with IE under JQuery 1.4.1 - change events on combo boxes were not firing if the keyboard was used to make the change.

Seems to have been fixed in JQuery 1.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#item').live('change keypress', function() { /* code */ });
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated. Use `on` instead, and if you're not using jQuery 1.7 or above, use `delegate`.