# How to hide/show select boxes depending on other choosed select box option?

Tags: javascript

Im a newbie in javascript and i really aprecciate any ideas of how i can do this...

I have one select box. Depending on the option i choose, the other select boxes that are supposed to be "invisible" one of them becomes visible.

I dont want to use jquery, because im still a newbie in js.

Sorry for my english :P

I will put some code for give the example:

```
<select id="tipos_evento">
        <option value="">choose an option to see the corresponding select box</option>
         <option value="tipoe01">option_one</option>
         <option value="tipoe02">option_two</option>
         <option value="tipoe03">ssss</option>
         <option value="tipoe04">ddd</option>
</select>

<select id="option_one">
        <option value="">ss</option>
         <option value="c">Cffs</option>
         <option value="d">s</option>
         <option value="tipoe03">ssss</option>
         <option value="tipoe04">ddd</option>
</select>

    <select id="option_two">
        <option value="">ss</option>
         <option value="c">Cffs</option>
         <option value="d">s</option>
         <option value="tipoe03">ssss</option>
         <option value="tipoe04">ddd</option>
</select>
```

But i think the challenge for me is to show the one that i choosed and to hide the other ones...
Thank u for the replies

Ive been trying to work out the Justin Johnson function, but it didnt work for internet explorer 7 and 8.

I will post the code for anyone that can help me.
Ive changed the `style.display = "none"; for`style.cssText='display: none';
but only worked when the page loaded. Now when i change the select box, nothing happens.

Here is the code(its big, i will optimize it with loops when this works):

```
var attachEvento = function(node, event, listener, useCapture) {
  // Method for FF, Opera, Chrome, Safari
  if (window.addEventListener ) {
    node.addEventListener(event, listener, useCapture || false);
  }
  // IE has its own method
  else {
    node.attachEvent('on'+event, listener);
  }
};


// Once the window loads and the DOM is ready, attach the event to the main
attachEvento(window, "load", function() {
  var main_select = document.getElementById("tipos_evento");

   var option1 = document.getElementById("temas_conferencias"),
         option2 = document.getElementById("temas_cursos"),
         option3 = document.getElementById("temas_provas"),
         option4 = document.getElementById("temas_visitas"),
         option5 = document.getElementById("temas_ciencias"),
         option6 = document.getElementById("temas_dancas"),
         option7 = document.getElementById("temas_exposicoes"),
         option8 = document.getElementById("temas_multi"),
         option9 = document.getElementById("temas_musica"),
         option10 = document.getElementById("temas_teatro"),
         option11 = document.getElementById("temas_cultura"),
         option12 = document.getElementById("temas_desporto"),
         option13 = document.getElementById("temas_todos");


       option1.style.cssText='display: none';
       option2.style.cssText='display: none';
       option3.style.cssText='display: none';
       option4.style.cssText='display: none';
       option5.style.cssText='display: none';
       option6.style.cssText='display: none';
       option7.style.cssText='display: none';
       option8.style.cssText='display: none';
       option9.style.cssText='display: none';
       option10.style.cssText='display: none';
       option11.style.cssText='display: none';
       option12.style.cssText='display: none';
       option13.style.cssText='display: block';

  var selectHandler = function() {

     // Show and hide the appropriate select's
     switch(this.value) {
       case "8":
       // Conferências / colóquios
       option1.style.display = "";
       option2.style.display = "none";
       option3.style.display = "none";
       option4.style.display = "none";
       option5.style.display = "none";
       option6.style.display = "none";
       option7.style.display = "none";
       option8.style.display = "none";
       option9.style.display = "none";
       option10.style.display = "none";
       option11.style.display = "none";
       option12.style.display = "none";
       option13.style.display = "none";
       break;
       case "10":
       // Cursos/workshops
       option1.style.cssText='display: none';
       option2.style.cssText='display: block';
       option3.style.cssText='display: none';
       option4.style.cssText='display: none';
       option5.style.cssText='display: none';
       option6.style.cssText='display: none';
       option7.style.cssText='display: none';
       option8.style.cssText='display: none';
       option9.style.cssText='display: none';
       option10.style.cssText='display: none';
       option11.style.cssText='display: none';
       option12.style.cssText='display: none';
       option13.style.cssText='display: none';
       break;
       case "7":
       // provas
       option1.style.cssText='display: none';
       option2.style.cssText='display: none';
       option3.style.cssText='display: block';
       option4.style.cssText='display: none';
       option5.style.cssText='display: none';
       option6.style.cssText='display: none';
       option7.style.cssText='display: none';
       option8.style.cssText='display: none';
       option9.style.cssText='display: none';
       option10.style.cssText='display: none';
       option11.style.cssText='display: none';
       option12.style.cssText='display: none';
       option13.style.cssText='display: none';
       break;
       case "9":
       // visitas/observações
       option1.style.cssText='display: none';
       option2.style.cssText='display: none';
       option3.style.cssText='display: none';
       option4.style.cssText='display: block';
        option5.style.cssText='display: none';
       option6.style.cssText='display: none';
       option7.style.cssText='display: none';
       option8.style.cssText='display: none';
       option9.style.cssText='display: none';
       option10.style.cssText='display: none';
       option11.style.cssText='display: none';
       option12.style.cssText='display: none';
       option13.style.cssText='display: none';
       break;
       case "12":
       // ciencia
       option1.style.cssText='display: none';
       option2.style.cssText='display: none';
       option3.style.cssText='display: none';
       option4.style.cssText='display: none';
       option5.style.cssText='display: block';
       option6.style.cssText='display: none';
       option7.style.cssText='display: none';
       option8.style.cssText='display: none';
       option9.style.cssText='display: none';
       option10.style.cssText='display: none';
       option11.style.cssText='display: none';
       option12.style.cssText='display: none';
       option13.style.cssText='display: none';
       break;
       case "2":
       // danças
       option1.style.cssText='display: none';
       option2.style.cssText='display: none';
       option3.style.cssText='display: none';
       option4.style.cssText='display: none';
       option5.style.cssText='display: none';
       option6.style.cssText='display: block';
       option7.style.cssText='display: none';
       option8.style.cssText='display: none';
       option9.style.cssText='display: none';
       option10.style.cssText='display: none';
       option11.style.cssText='display: none';
       option12.style.cssText='display: none';
       option13.style.cssText='display: none';
       break;
       case "1":
       // exposiçoes
       option1.style.cssText='display: none';
       option2.style.cssText='display: none';
       option3.style.cssText='display: none';
       option4.style.cssText='display: none';
       option5.style.cssText='display: none';
       option6.style.cssText='display: none';
       option7.style.cssText='display: block';
       option8.style.cssText='display: none';
       option9.style.cssText='display: none';
       option10.style.cssText='display: none';
       option11.style.cssText='display: none';
       option12.style.cssText='display: none';
       option13.style.cssText='display: none';
       break;
       case "3":
       // multi
       option1.style.cssText='display: none';
       option2.style.cssText='display: none';
       option3.style.cssText='display: none';
       option4.style.cssText='display: none';
       option5.style.cssText='display: none';
       option6.style.cssText='display: none';
       option7.style.cssText='display: none';
       option8.style.cssText='display: block';
       option9.style.cssText='display: none';
       option10.style.cssText='display: none';
       option11.style.cssText='display: none';
       option12.style.cssText='display: none';
       option13.style.cssText='display: none';
       break;
       case "4":
       // musica
       option1.style.cssText='display: none';
       option2.style.cssText='display: none';
       option3.style.cssText='display: none';
       option4.style.cssText='display: none';
       option5.style.cssText='display: none';
       option6.style.cssText='display: none';
       option7.style.cssText='display: none';
       option8.style.cssText='display: none';
       option9.style.cssText='display: block';
       option10.style.cssText='display: none';
       option11.style.cssText='display: none';
       option12.style.cssText='display: none';
       option13.style.cssText='display: none';
       break;
       case "5":
       // teatro
       option1.style.cssText='display: none';
       option2.style.cssText='display: none';
       option3.style.cssText='display: none';
       option4.style.cssText='display: none';
       option5.style.cssText='display: none';
       option6.style.cssText='display: none';
       option7.style.cssText='display: none';
       option8.style.cssText='display: none';
       option9.style.cssText='display: none';
       option10.style.cssText='display: block';
       option11.style.cssText='display: none';
       option12.style.cssText='display: none';
       option13.style.cssText='display: none';
       break;
       case "6":
       // Cultura(outros)
       option1.style.cssText='display: none';
       option2.style.cssText='display: none';
       option3.style.cssText='display: none';
       option4.style.cssText='display: none';
       option5.style.cssText='display: none';
       option6.style.cssText='display: none';
       option7.style.cssText='display: none';
       option8.style.cssText='display: none';
       option9.style.cssText='display: none';
       option10.style.cssText='display: none';
       option11.style.cssText='display: block';
       option12.style.cssText='display: none';
       option13.style.cssText='display: none';
       break;
       case "48":
       // Desporto
       option1.style.cssText='display: none';
       option12.style.cssText='display: block';
        option2.style.cssText='display: none';
       option3.style.cssText='display: none';
       option4.style.cssText='display: none';
        option5.style.cssText='display: none';
       option6.style.cssText='display: none';
       option7.style.cssText='display: none';
       option8.style.cssText='display: none';
       option9.style.cssText='display: none';
       option10.style.cssText='display: none';
       option11.style.cssText='display: none';
       option13.style.cssText='display: none';
       break;
       default:
       // Hide all
       option1.style.cssText='display: none';
       option2.style.cssText='display: none';
       option3.style.cssText='display: none';
       option4.style.cssText='display: none';
        option5.style.cssText='display: none';
       option6.style.cssText='display: none';
       option7.style.cssText='display: none';
       option8.style.cssText='display: none';
       option9.style.cssText='display: none';
       option10.style.cssText='display: none';
       option11.style.cssText='display: none';
       option13.style.cssText='display: block';
     }
  };

  // Use the onchange and onkeypress events to detect when the
  // value of main_select has changed
  attachEvento(main_select, "change", selectHandler);
  attachEvento(main_select, "keypress", selectHandler);
});
```

Comment: Please, include some code to be more precise

Comment: Hey mate, you can't have "/" in your element ID's.   Also, I've never done this so I can't say for sure, buy you might have some problems using accented characters in ID's as well.  Can anyone comment on this?

Comment: thank u Justin i just inserted some copy/paste text..in reality i didnt use that :)

Comment: the ids dont have any punctuation :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I generally use mootools, but this should be generic.  I can't speak to cross-browser issues, though.

```
<select id='main_select' onchange='show_select()'>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
<select id='select_1' style='display:none'></select>
<select id='select_2' style='display:none'></select>

function show_select()
{
  var main_select = document.getElementById("main_select");
  var select_1 = document.getElementById("select_1");
  var select_2 = document.getElementById("select_2");

  var desired_box = main_select.options[main_select.selectedIndex].value;
  if(desired_box == 1) {
    select_1.style.display = '';
    select_2.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    select_2.style.display = '';
    select_1.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: obtrusive use of javascript.  `onchange` should not be in the html

Comment: @Justin: for beginners, using the html attributes is much simpler than understanding all the event registration models.

Comment: If he wants to learn JavaScript, it is even more important that he be shown the proper way of doing things.  There's no point in learning antiquated methods that are popularly viewed as wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can handle the change event:

```
document.getElementById('selectBox').onchange = function () {
  var selectedValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; // get the selected value

  // Depending on the value selected you can show or hide other elements:

  if (selectedValue == "1") { 
    document.getElementById('element1').style.display = 'none';  // hide element1
    document.getElementById('element2').style.display = ''; // show element2
  }
};
```

**Note:** In your edit, the last two select boxes have **invalid characters** for the **ID** attribute.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

More information [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery makes things easier, there's no reason not to use it.

But either way, you need to use the onChange event to read which options are selected, and then set the css visible property on the other boxes that you want to show and hide.

```
<select name="sbox" onChange="event()">
<option value="option 1">option 1</option>
<option value="option 2">option 2</option>
</select>
```

and then,

```
function event() {
  switch (sbox.selectedindex) {
    case 0:
      someOtherSelect.style.visiblity = 'visible';
    ...
  }
}
```

This example assumes you already have variables with sbox and someOtherSelect set in the onload event.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something quick and dirty, using proper event attachment methods (but not tested):

```
var attachEvent = function(node, event, listener, useCapture) {
  // Method for FF, Opera, Chrome, Safari
  if ( window.addEventListener ) {
    node.addEventListener(event, listener, useCapture || false);
  }
  // IE has its own method
  else {
    node.attachEvent('on'+event, listener);
  }
};

// Once the window loads and the DOM is ready, attach the event to the main
attachEvent(window, "load", function() {
  var main_select = document.getElementById("tipos_evento");

  var selectHandler = function() {
     var option1 = document.getElementById("option_one"),
         option2 = document.getElementById("option_two");

     // Show and hide the appropriate select's
     if ( this.value == "tipoe1" ) {
       // Show option1, hide option2
       option1.style.display = "";
       option2.style.display = "none";
     } else if ( this.value == "tipoe2" ) {
       // Hide option1, show option2
       option1.style.display = "none";
       option2.style.display = "";
     } else {
       // Hide both
       option1.style.display = "none";
       option2.style.display = "none";
     }
  };

  // Use the onchange and onkeypress events to detect when the 
  // value of main_select has changed
  attachEvent(main_select, "change", selectHandler);
  attachEvent(main_select, "keypress", selectHandler);
});
```

For an explanation of why you need both `onchange` and `onkeypress`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237164/jquery-listbox-change-event-does-not-fire-on-keyboard-scrolling/1237226#1237226).

Look up the [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) and [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343(VS.85).aspx) methods for more information on browser specific event handling and their differences.

And kudos on not wanting to go with jquery so you can actually learn the language.

Comment: Thank u Justin. I didnt tried the code yet, but this hides the other select boxes if one option is choosed?

Comment: I see that you've added example html.  I'll change my code to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Justin. One question. Why u didnt use the "var" word to initialize the option2 variable and used on the option1?

Comment: I did ;) Notice that there is a comma in the middle `var option1 = ..., option2 = ...;`

Comment: Just two more questions Justin.
If i want to add more "option" variables to have more selects, it is just add more vars? I tried to use the switch case but it didnt work..any guide lines??THank u for ur patiente

Comment: 1) ya, just more `var optionX = document.getElementBy('option_x');` 2) you should be able to do `switch (this.value) { case "tipeo1": ... break; case "tipeo2": ... break; }` and so on

Comment: Hi Justin, ive been testing ur code, and in Internet explorer 7 and 8 the select boxes dont hide.Just to let u know. Thanks

Comment: It has to do with the attachEvent i think. I will search for answers

Comment: for the attachEvent i found the solution. But now, when i change the select box, the function dont work. It doesnt change the select box visibility....

Comment: object.attachEvent is IE's method for attaching events without overwriting previously attached events (as opposed to `object.onsomeevent = function() {};` which will overwrite anything previously set.)  `object.addEventListener` is Firefox's equivalent.  The function that I wrote, `attachEvent`, which determines the appropriate method to use based on the browser) , perhaps should have been named differently to avoid confusion.  Sorry about that.  Have you figured out your problem completely yet?